# Bar button item not shown in navigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I'm working on an app where my initial view controller is embedded in a Navigation Controller and Tab bar controller.

In my app I have 3 different tabs, one tab is the settings view. This is a tableview with 5 buttons. every button will show the same view controller when it's touched.

When I touch on one of the buttons, I still have a nice green navigation bar, but my buttons do not work.

I tried dragging a Navigation Item into the view in my storyboard and then put a bar button item in it. I can see the button in my storyboard, but it won't show up in my app when I run it.

I also added the following code to my viewDidLoad():

```
let leftItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "< Back", style: .Done, target: self, action: Selector("Save"))
let rightItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: .Plain, target: self, action: Selector("Save"))

//self.parentViewController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem // also doesn't work

navigationController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem
navigationController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightItem
```

But it won't have any effect.

I checked if the correct UIViewController was assigned to my view in the storyboard, did several Clean builds (CMD + Shift + K) and Rebuilds (CMD + B).

The following images are a screenshot of a part of my storyboard and a screenshot of my app at the view where the buttons won't show up.

**EDIT**

Added a new screenshot about the controls in the view. These do not work with **or** without the additional code in my viewDidLoad.

[image: Screenshot of my Storyboard]

[image: Screenshot of my app where the buttons should show up]

[image: Screenshot of the the setup of the controls in my view]

Comment: Delete your first navigation controller, second you dont need to add back button just use push segue, third try to use self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem(try adding self at the beginning.)

Comment: @ErsinSezgin Thanks! My problem is solved. When you can place an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete your first navigation controller, second you dont need to add back button just use push segue, third try to use self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem(try adding self at the beginning.) *Original answer was a comment.

Answer (score 14):

Instead of

```
navigationController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem
```

do

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem
```

**Update** I suggest you add them directly in the storyboard to your Viewcontroller

Comment: Sorry, but that does not have any effect.

Comment: updated my answer, can't you add them via storyboard? You have to drag&drop in a navigationItem first

Comment: Nope that's not working. I updated my question with a screenshot of the controls I have added to the view in my storyboard.

Comment: did you drag the navigationItem to the navigationBar? Seems like you just dragged it in your ViewController

Comment: I just did it again, but there seems no navigationBar available. When I add one, I can see a small line under my current navigation bar. Removing the first Navigation Controller (which was the initial view controller) solved my problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

I also ran into same issue.

In iOS 11 it's working fine but for iOS 10 or less it was not showing UIBarButtonItems which added programatically.

Please assign frame to UIBarButtonItem.

```html
let button =  UIButton(type: .custom)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "img_name"), for:.normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnAction), for: .touchUpInside)
button.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:32, height:32)
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```

Answer (score 2):

I had two segues: one via a storyboard segue, and one programmatic. The storyboard segue showed the buttons as expected. The progammatic segue, however, showed the view without the buttons.

For the programmatic segue, I was using:

```
present(theNewVC, animated: true)
```

The buttons appeared and functioned correctly when I changed that to:

```
show(theNewVC, sender: self)
```

Per the documentation, `present(...)` presents the view controller modally. Apparently a modal view controller doesn't get the nav bar buttons. I further confirmed this by changing my storyboard segue to `Present Modally` - and the buttons disappeared there as well.

(Using Xcode 9, Swift 4)

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];

    [button setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"BtnBack"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button.imageView setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithCustomView:button];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
```

this Code Write on ViewWillAppear method.

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me recently. I was doing what Ersin mentioned, but to no avail. Backtracked a little more and found out that this was the culprit:

`nav.pushViewController(notifications, animated: false)
nav.pushViewController(interactionCreateOrEdit, animated: false)`

I changed it to

`nav.setViewControllers([notifications, interactionCreateOrEdit], animated: false)`

and the UIBarButtonItems started appearing again.